# Using sass with vue 3

Tags: sass, vuejs3

I have a project that compiles using normal css, but I want to use sass markup.

In Header.vue this doesn't work:

```
<style lang="sccs" scoped>
   div.menu {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      height: 65px;
      background: $header;
   }
```

It does compile if I eliminate the lang="scss" and the sass variable.

I have the following in vue.config.js:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  publicPath: '/dist/',
  pluginOptions: {
    "style-resources-loader": {
      preProcessor: "scss",
      patterns: [path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/styles/_colors.scss")]
    }
  },
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        data: '@import "@/styles/_colors.scss";'
      }
    }
  },
  configureWebpack: {
    module: {
      rules: [{
        test: /\.s(c|a)ss$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            // Requires sass-loader@^7.0.0
            options: {
              implementation: require('sass'),
              fiber: require('fibers'),
            },
          },
        ],
      }, ],
   },
  }
};
```

I get the following error when it builds. It builds fine without the scss.

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:11)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js
 * ./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| 
>   div.menu {
|     position: fixed;
|     top: 0;
```

Answer (score 4):

You wrong 'scss spelling in style tag of Header.vue. Please change 'sccs' to 'scss'.